# How to get previous row count and column values in xlsx using python list iteration

Tags: python

I need to get row count and particular column values using python list iteration can any one help me on this.
for every row in excel i need to get url,username and password.
for that i have used the below code.

```
xl_workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file)
 sheet = xl_workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
 vendor = [[sheet.cell_value(r,c) for c in range(sheet.ncols)] for r in range(1,sheet.nrows)]

 for i in vendor:
    user_name = i[1]
    password=i[2]
```

like this when first iteration is completed, i need to check previous username and password and need to compare with current iteration values.
Can anyone help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I deal with excel or any other list file input, I always create a list before reading the file, and appending each line to a list so I can access them later.

If you need to compare to any given username/password I would use something like the following:
[Putting into list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E35av.png)

This allows you to get values from any username/password.